# " malloc error pointer being freed was not allocated " error only in simulator:

Tags: c++, ios

When I debug on actual devices, there is no error, but when I use the simulator, Xcode's debugger console displays the following error when running:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0xaaaaaaaa: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The error always happens at the same line, which is in the constructor of another class:

```
Segment *segment = new Segment(0.0,0.0,3.0,1.3,10);
this->segments.push_back(segment); // Malloc error at this line
```

My Segment class:

```
class Segment {

private:

    float ajc;
    float frl;
    std::unordered_map<int,int> jgrc;
    std::vector<int> lorb;

public:

    std::tuple<float,float> getMjt();
    float getBuw();
    ….

    Segment(float a, float f,float g, float lo, float u){
    ……
    };
};
```

On the simulator, regardless of iOS version, the error appears. On devices, regardless of version, there is no error.

I have heard about the rule of 3, but in this case I don't think I need to apply it because the default compiler supplied code should work (unless I'm mistaken). **What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this ?** **Since there is no error reported on devices, should i ignore it ?**

Comment: `Segment *segment = new Segment(0.0,0.0,3.0,1.3,10);
this->segments.push_back(segment);`  Why a vector of `Segment` pointers?  Seems to me a vector of Segment objects would work just fine.

Comment: You didn't gave info about `segments`? i mean how are you creating that?

Comment: Look at `malloc: *** error for object 0xaaaaaaaa: pointer being freed was not allocated`. That one clearly means that the pointer wasn't initialized correctly (that value is a debug pre initialization)

Comment: I suspect there is a problem in the way you initialized `segments` since a `std::vector` doesn't crash if you put a random pointer value in it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just tried pointers, because the error popped up when using objects. But the error remains with pointers as well.

Comment: @RupeshYadav. It is initialised using "new" in the preceding statement

Comment: @meneldal The 0xaaaaaaa is because I enabled "Scribble" in the Xcode debugger, so that Scribble fills allocated memory with 0xAA. So actually it just means that the memory was initialised (i think)

Comment: That also mean that you didn't write over it. A pointer shouldn't remain to an uninitialised value. That value isn't the one of the memory pointed by the pointer, it's the value of the pointer.

Comment: @meneldal But then why does it only appear in the simulator then ? My app should behave abnormally, but it appears to actually work.. Could this be a copy problem ?

Comment: Most likely the uninitialized value is `nullptr` because most random memory tends to be 0. When you call delete with `nullptr` nothing happens so you wouldn't notice.

Comment: @John A C++ program will not behave deterministically when you have these types of bugs.  So you shouldn't spend a lot of time on "why does it work here but not there".

Comment: @John `I just tried pointers, because the error popped up when using objects. `  You should not have done that.  Your `Segment` class contains two floats, a vector, a map, and a tuple.  These members have correct copy semantics, thus using objects lessens the chance of an error occurring.  If you had an error when using objects, then you should have gone through the rest of your code and seeing where you are still using pointers and `new`.  By changing your code to use pointers, you made the problem harder to debug, and may have introduced new bugs.

Comment: @John yesterday i m talking about segments not segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution works, but I don't understand why. If someone with more c++ can explain it well, I will mark that as the correct answer.

The following code runs in the constructor of my class that creates the segments:

```
Segment *segment = new Segment(0.0,0.0,3.0,1.3,10);
this->segments.push_back(segment); // Malloc error at this line
```

First, I used objects instead of the pointer. Then I moved the code out of the constructor, and instead call it immediately after creating an instance of the class.

Say my class is:

```
class MyClass{
    std::vector<Segment> segments;
}
```

I do :

```
MyClass *foo = new MyClass();
foo->createSegments();
```

Where:

```
createSegments(){
    Segment segment = Segment(0.0,0.0,3.0,1.3,10);
    segments.push_back(segment);
}
```

I'm not very experienced with C++, so I don't know why this works.I also still don't know why the original error only appeared in the simulator.

Comment: When you use objects, you are lessening, if not totally eliminating the chance of doing something incorrectly wrt pointers and dynamically allocated memory management.  Your `Segment` class, on the first cut of your program, should not have used pointers at all.  It is copyable since all it contains are members that are safely copyable.  Only for a valid reason should you then start to use pointers, and even then, use a smart pointer and not raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

First put a NULL check to avoid the run time error. I tried a pseudo code on VS and it seemed to work. I hope your vector is similar.

```
Segment *segment = new Segment(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.3, 10);
std::vector<Segment*> vec;
if (NULL != segment)
    vec.push_back(segment);
```

I think there is some problem with your simulator not working fine.

Comment: Well you can actually send `nullptr` in a `std::vector` and it's not going to crash

Comment: Checking for NULL in this case doesn't work, as `new` throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception on failure (assuming that you are using standard C++).  Using `nothrow` allows the NULL check to work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  and menedal : makes sense!!! I just have a habit of checking for NULL everywhere :) But still can't figure out why the exception would occur. I doubt the simulator only.

Comment: The simulator is making an initialization on a uninitialized pointer to `0xaaaaaaaa` instead of no initialization (most likely to be `nullptr` by chance) which wouldn't cause a `delete` to fail. It is very common to do this in a debug environment.

Comment: @Spanky segment is never NULL for me. I set a breakpoint on malloc_error _break, so there is no problem there.

Comment: @John : I believe meneldal explanation is the correct one. It is a problem with the debug environment.

Comment: It's not a problem in the debug environment because most likely there's a bug in the app that you're just not seeing the rest of time. I have many programs that work "most of the time" in release but never in debug because of a segfault.

Comment: I can't figure out a plan of action. Could this be because I am not defining copy, move and assignment constructors ?

Comment: Most likely the problem is outside the code you've put here, something badly uninitialized in `this`